# codesign Preference Pane results in "object file format unrecognized, invalid, or unsuitable"

Tags: macos, code-signing, osx-gatekeeper

I'm trying to codesign a preference pane using my Developer ID certificate. Here is the command I'm using in the terminal:

```
codesign -v -f -s <MyCertificate> AppTrap.prefPane
```

And here's the output:

```
AppTrap.prefPane: object file format unrecognized, invalid, or unsuitable
```

**Am I doing something wrong in codesigning a preference pane?** Are preference panes even codesign-able?

Answer (score 0):

Your command is correct and I'm able to codesign a preference pane bundle with it.

However, codesigning a preference pane will not give you much advantage as Gatekeeper will reject it as of now. Apple [is deemed to have said](https://openradar.appspot.com/25618668)(via [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25152451/are-mac-app-store-code-sign-resource-envelopes-always-version-1)):

> Please know that our engineering team has determined that this issue
>   behaves as intended based on the information provided.
>
> Gatekeeper (as of 10.11.4) rejects anything that isn’t an app (or “like” an
>   app, such a widget). This is part of a general hardening effort.