# Error when export archive

Tags: ios, ipa

I have problem with using Export function in Xcode ("Your account already have distribution certificate") so I used solution with `xcodebuild`. It produce IPA file but I see this in console:

```
### Checking original app
+ /usr/bin/codesign --verify -vvvv /.../My.app
Program /usr/bin/codesign returned 1 : [/.../My.app: resource envelope is obsolete
]
Codesign check fails : /.../My.app: resource envelope is obsolete
```

Is it a problem from my side and how to solve it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are using Mac OSX 10.9.5 or later, then there is an issue with OS codesigning with V2 signature.

So, use --no-strict flag with codesign --verify to getover this error.

If you're using PackageApplication to create an .ipa file, then

Edit the PackageApplication perl script tool using vi PackageApplication command and update codesign function occurrences to pass "--no-strict" parameter.

Example:

> my $result = runCmd("/usr/bin/codesign", "--verify", **"--no-strict"**,
>   "-vvvv", , $plugin );

I was facing same and got following response from Apple Dev Team. The issue is resolved for me.

> The command line tool “codesign” has changed in 10.9.5 and 10.10, you need to pass “--no-strict” option to the command, (the problem has been reported and will be fixed).
>   To workaround the problem, please save a copy and modify PackageApplication to pass “—no-strict” to codesign, you can locate PackageApplication by running the following:-
>   xcrun -sdk iphoneos -f PackageApplication